# I need to implement a database. What now?

Tags: c#, mysql, user-interface

So I have a relative that needs me to develop 2 programs for his business. The first program's purpose is to create user-friendly and printable order forms for the sale representative, input it into a database, and be able to search for the order forms through different criteria. Id like it to be encrypted, have a username and password, and have multiple levels of authority. For example, the owner can delete orders, the manager can edit orders(or make small modifications), the secretary can only add new orders. Id like to make it possibly accessible from the internet (v2.0).

The second program is a 2-part management program. Its purpose is to be able to track every order through each part of the manufacturing process. For example, we would put a computer at each of the 5 departments(one for each process), and have each empplyee at that department enter in a unique username and password, and accept a job. When he is done, he log's in to the program, and tells the program that the job is done, and it was passed over to the next department. The program would record the employee that has accepted the job, the time it started, the time it finished, at which department the order is currently at, etc. The manager using the program should be able to see every job that is currently being worked on and which department every job  is at.

I am familiar with c++ and am tackling c# as of right now. I want to build a GUI and use c# for both programs. In terms of databases, I dont know much. I've read about mySQL and wanted to get a few different opinions before I start working. One concern is that the database will include data in different languages, so I must be aware of that.

What do you think?

edit: The second program would include some networking, where would I start in regards to how the "slave" computers would communicate with the master computer? They will all be on a local network.

Comment: This is painfully too broad for Stack Overflow.  In addition, both applications are demonstrating sophisticated feature sets across a broad array of app dev disciplines.  If you're not even sure how to get started, perhaps this is a little aggressive?

Comment: Well this is a long term project, if you can at least point me in the direction of what I should look up, that will help me get a better idea. I have already created a user interface for the sales program. I just need some guidance in regards to databases.

Comment: If you could boil your question down to a very specific question about the differences in how databases handle multi-language support, you might have a decent candidate for a question.  But as it stands right now, your question is impossible to answer in an SO-approved manner.

Comment: What do you mean by "already created a user interface"? You have drawn a few sketches, or you have created a working program that utilizes a framework, such as WinForm, WPF, or ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes, I built a working program using WPF. **I apologize, the title was misleading.** I need help tackling the next step.

Comment: maybe look at open source ERP software and maybe just fork and make it do what need to . or just use them to learn and decide how you want to approch it . [Google Search](https://www.google.com/#q=open+source+ERP)

Comment: Oh, you've chosen a tough path. If your goal is Internet accessibility, perhaps it's a good idea to switch to ASP.NET MVC now, before you've done serious development. Or you can consider outsourcing your project. Anyway, as @David says, your question is off-topic for stackoverflow, so maybe we should stop here.